# json_encode return encoded utf-8 string

Tags: php, json, utf-8

on shared apache server which host my website I can not set default server settings to utf-8

and  in PHP json_encode return encoded utf-8 string from text like:
مرتضی
to :
\u0645\u0631\u062a\u0636\u06cc

how can I prevent this or  how return it back to original text encoding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the [`JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php) flag:

```
echo json_encode($str, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```